# How to use useContext to translate different pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

I'm trying to understand 'useContext' to translate different Components of my application. In my code I'm receiving the error "language, languages, and handleIdiom is not defined". I understand that in my "Menu" Component I didn't define them, but in the "Languages" Component that it is my provider, I defined all.

I thought since my "Menu" is wrapper with , I could use it. Also, could you please look at the code and tell me what is wrong and what changes are required to achieve my goal?

**Context:**

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";

export const languages = {
  en: {
    about: "about",
    project: "project",
    contact: "contact",
    slogan: "Think the Design, and I design the Code.",
    button: "Learn more",
  },
  ptbr: {
    about: "sobre",
    project: "projetos",
    contact: "contatos",
    slogan: "Think the Design, and I design the Code.",
    button: "Learn more",
  },
  jp: {
    about: "nihon",
    project: "nihon",
    contact: "nihon",
    slogan: "nihon",
    button: "nihon",
  },
  ru: {
    about: "руский",
    project: "руский",
    contact: "руский",
    slogan: "руский",
    button: "руский",
  },
};

export const LanguagesContext = React.createContext({ languages });

function Language() {
  const [idiom, setIdiom] = useState("en");

  const handleIdiom = (language) => (e) => {
    setIdiom(language);
  };

  return (
    <LanguagesContext.Provider
      value={{ idiom, setIdiom }}
    ></LanguagesContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useIdiom() {
  const context = useContext(LanguagesContext);
  const { idiom, setIdiom } = context;
  return { idiom, setIdiom };
}

export default Language;
```

**Menu:**

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import "./MenuStyle.scss";
import { FaBars } from "react-icons/fa";
import br from "../../assets/menu/brazil.svg";
import en from "../../assets/menu/eua.svg";
import ru from "../../assets/menu/russia.svg";
import jp from "../../assets/menu/japan.svg";

import { useIdiom } from "../../provider/Language.jsx";

import LanguagesProvider from "../../provider/Language";

function Menu() {
  // burger menu
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
  const Close = () => setClick(false);

  // tradution
  const idiom = useIdiom();

  return (
    <LanguagesProvider>
      <div>
        <div
          className={click ? "main-container" : ""}
          onClick={() => Close()}
        />

        <nav className="navbar" onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
          <div className="nav-container">
            <div exact to="/" className="nav-logo">
              <h1>Flávio</h1>
            </div>

            <div className="links">
              <ul className={click ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <a href="" activeClassName="active" className="nav-links">
                    {languages[language].about}
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <a href="" activeClassName="active" className="nav-links">
                    {languages[language].project}
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <a href="" activeClassName="active" className="nav-links">
                    {languages[language].contact}
                  </a>
                </li>

                <div className="flags-desktop">
                  <li>
                    <img src={en} alt="en" onClick={handleIdiom("en")} />
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src={br} alt="ptbr" onClick={handleIdiom("ptbr")} />
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src={ru} alt="ru" />
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src={jp} alt="jp" />
                  </li>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div className="flags">
              <img src={en} alt="en" />
              <img src={br} alt="ptbr" />
              <img src={ru} alt="ru" />
              <img src={jp} alt="jp" />
            </div>

            <div className="nav-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
              <i className={click ? "fa fa-times" : "fa fa-bars"}>
                <FaBars />
              </i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </LanguagesProvider>
  );
}

export default Menu;
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using the `useContext` hook? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: In the very bottom of the context. I added a function called useIdiom and assigned the useContext hook.

Comment: And here's me not scrolling down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should wrap components where we want have access to language in `Context.Provider`. Then we can have access to context using hook useContext. Also added logic to save selected language to localStorage. Can be done like this:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";

// App.js

const defaultLanguage = "br";
export const LanguageContext = React.createContext();

function App() {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState(() => {
    const langFromLocalStorage = window.localStorage.getItem("lang");

    return langFromLocalStorage ? langFromLocalStorage : defaultLanguage;
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("lang", language);
  }, [language]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <LanguageContext.Provider value={[language, setLanguage]}>
        <Menu />
        <HomeComponent />
      </LanguageContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

// Menu.js :
// import { LanguageContext } from "...";

function Menu() {
  const languages = {
    en: {
      about: "about",
      project: "project",
      contact: "contact",
      slogan: "Think the Design, and I design the Code.",
      button: "Learn more",
    },
    br: {
      about: "sobre",
      project: "projetos",
      contact: "contatos",
      slogan: "Think the Design, and I design the Code.",
      button: "Learn more",
    },
    jp: {
      about: "nihon",
      project: "nihon",
      contact: "nihon",
      slogan: "nihon",
      button: "nihon",
    },
    ru: {
      about: "руский",
      project: "руский",
      contact: "руский",
      slogan: "руский",
      button: "руский",
    },
  };

  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const Close = () => setClick(false);

  const [language, setLanguage] = useContext(LanguageContext);
  console.log(`language`, language);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div
          className={click ? "main-container" : ""}
          onClick={() => Close()}
        />

        <nav className="navbar" onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
          <div className="nav-container">
            <div className="links">
              <h1>Current Language is: {language}</h1>
              <ul className={click ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <a href="" activeClassName="active" className="nav-links">
                    {languages[language].about}
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <a href="" activeClassName="active" className="nav-links">
                    {languages[language].project}
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <a href="" activeClassName="active" className="nav-links">
                    {languages[language].contact}
                  </a>
                </li>

                <div className="flags-desktop">
                  <li>
                    <img
                      src={"en"}
                      alt="en"
                      onClick={() => setLanguage("en")}
                    />
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img
                      src={"br"}
                      alt="ptbr"
                      onClick={() => setLanguage("br")}
                    />
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img
                      src={"ru"}
                      alt="ru"
                      onClick={() => setLanguage("ru")}
                    />
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img
                      src={"jp"}
                      alt="jp"
                      onClick={() => setLanguage("jp")}
                    />
                  </li>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

const HomeComponent = () => {
  const [language] = useContext(LanguageContext);
  console.log(`language`, language);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>HomeComponent</h1>
      <h1>Current Language is: {language}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Спасибо! One thing I understand from your comment. I was wrapping the wrong content.

I'm trying to achieve something different or I didn't explain myself well.

Example:

In the Menu, once I change the language option, I'd like to also change the language in the Menu Component, I also would like the language in the Home component to be changed.

Comment: That's why I removed the languages={...) from the "Menu" component and created a provider called "Languages". Because my initial goal is to share between all components.

Comment: You can put your `<HomeComponent />` inside `<LanguageContext.Provider />` in `<App/>` and get current language there. I updated my answer. Added fake `<HomeComponent />`

Comment: Sure you can have `dictionary` for all pages you need , then just import it where you need it

Comment: I receive the following error: ×
TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Because of the line const [language, setLanguage] = useContext(LanguageContext);

Comment: This whole code in answer is working, just copy-paste it to 1 file. Then you can see what is different in your code.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. The code indeed is working. I found the mistake, I was trying to use your example in a different way.

Comment: Could you please share a link about the dictionary or doc?

Comment: You can look my project with translations on GitHub: https://github.com/KonstantinModin/anastasia-site